# Having a problem encrypting password from a Spring Boot using OpenShift

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot app reading encrypted password for my database details using OpenShift.

Here is my `application.yml` looks like

````
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

  datasource:
    username: admin
    password: '{cipher}600547f6485119b897e2fbeaee2786addb7550d967f2841f1643ws9'
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver ```
i'm getting this error

``` 19-06-20 15:08:58.683  WARN 1 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.c.c.s.e.CipherEnvironmentEncryptor   : Cannot decrypt key: spring.jpa.datasource.password (class java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to invoke Cipher due to bad padding)
2019-06-20 15:12:06.884  WARN 1 --- [nio-8888-exec-9] o.s.c.c.s.e.CipherEnvironmentEncryptor   : Cannot decrypt key: spring.datasource.password (class java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to invoke Cipher due to bad padding)
2019-06-20 15:12:29.940  WARN 1 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.s.c.c.s.e.CipherEnvironmentEncryptor   : Cannot decrypt key: spring.jpa.datasource.password (class java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to invoke Cipher due to bad padding)
2019-06-20 15:12:55.770 WARN 1 --- [nio-8888-exec-7] o.s.c.c.s.e.CipherEnvironmentEncryptor : Cannot decrypt key: spring.datasource.password (class java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to invoke Cipher due to bad padding) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you configured JCE in your system and also verify whether encrypt-key was presented in bootstrap.yml file .

Comment: JCE and the encrypt-key are both there
I'm also confused because is requesting this "Cannot decrypt key: spring.jpa.datasource.password" which i dnt at all

Comment: Then encrypt again and try to decrypt.

Comment: problem solved. while i was encrypting my password there was an extra empty space that was causing the issue. all i had to do is to remove the space ``` spring encrypt ***** --key password ```